# typescript angular2 template queryParams

Tags: templates, angular, typescript, concatenation, addition

I am trying to build an Angular 2 app with routing. I have a link in my template that looks like this:

```xml
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['/Foo']" [queryParams]="{page:1+curr}">Next</a>
```

In my component class `curr` is defined as

```xml
curr: number = 0
```

I want the linked URL to be

```xml
/Foo?page=1
```

instead it looks like the `1` and `curr` are being concatenated and the URL is

```xml
/Foo?page10
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works fine...? I tested it, it adds 1 and curr correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```xml
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['/Foo']" [queryParams]="{page:'1'+curr}">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that even though `curr` was declared `curr: number = 0` it was later asigned to a variable returned via AJAX that happened to be a string

```
curr = data.current // current is a string
```

I expected this to be caught by the transpiler but I was not running a verstion of lint.
 Therefore when trying to add a string and a number the number coerced into a string and the result was concatenation.